# When should I flag a question as "should be closed" when I have enough reputation to vote to close?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

I noticed that on sites where I have enough reputation to cast close votes - or where I am a moderator - I can still flag a question as "should be closed" and then select one of the reasons given. This seems a little pointless; wouldn't it be more expedient to simply cast a close vote? Furthermore, as a moderator, there's really no point in flagging at all.

Are there any situations where I should use the "should be closed" flag if I can vote to close or close the question?

Comment: LOL try you can't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open the flag dialog and select "should be closed", you are redirected to the dialog where you can cast an actual close vote. So when you have got enough reputation, you cannot flag to close anymore, only vote to close.

Comment: Oh, man, I should have tried that out. Thank you.

Comment: Also, the dialog button is "Vote to Close" in this case instead of "Flag".